# How adaptive set items in rows

Tags: html, css, layout, css-grid

I have arrays of cards, card can take or 25% wide of screen, or 50%.
So its objects like this : { name: 1, size: 25% }.
After filtering array via js im getting a new array of cards and i need layout cards in grid in rows with wide 100%. So it can take 25 50 25, 50 50, 25 25 50 ...ect. So i think it can be make with grid-auto-flow property. But im not so good with grids yet.

```
.cards {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}
.card {
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  width: 25%;
}
.card-wide {
  width: 50%;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/23moj6z09y

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What do you have so far ? What's the desired output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider `1fr` for the unit and then tell if an element will span one or two columns:

```css
.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(4,1fr);
  grid-auto-flow:dense;
}
/*will take one column by default*/
.card {
  background:red;
}
.card-wide {
  grid-column:span 2; /*two column*/
  background:green;
}

.cards  > div {
  min-height:50px;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card-wide"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card-wide"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card-wide"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card-wide"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: tnx, dont know about span 2 =)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a 4-column layout using `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr)` and the `card-wide` elements can occupy two columns using `grid-column: span 2` - see demo below:

```css
.cards {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px; /* set a row height for illustration */
  grid-auto-flow: row dense; /* not compulsory here */
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}

.card-wide {
  grid-column: span 2; /* occupy two columns*/
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card card-wide"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card card-wide"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card card-wide"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card card-wide"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card card-wide"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card card-wide"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card card-wide"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: tnx, dont know about span 2 =)